# ASP.Net - Masked first 6 character on a string with dynamic length

Tags: c#, string

is it possible to masked a *first 6 characters* on a `string` if the `string` is dynamics on it's length?

Example, I have a string `"test123456789"` and I want a result of `"******3456789"` or a string of `"1234test"` and I want a result of `"******st"`. All I'm seeing sample codes here in masking are strings with a *static length*. Can anyone kindly help me with this? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and even quite easy, using simple string concatenation and `SubString`:

```
var original = "Some string here";
var target = "******" + ((original.Length > 6) ? original.Substring(6) : "") ;
```

If you want shorter strings to mask all characters but keep original length, you can do it like this:

```
var target = new string('*', Math.Min(original.Length, 6)) + ((original.Length > 6) ? original.Substring(6) : "") ;
```

This way, an input of `"123"` would return 3 asterisks (`"***"`). The first code I've shown will return 6 asterisks (`"******"`)

Comment: Thank you. Will try this and get back to you :)

Answer (score 2):

*Linq* is an alternative to `Substring` and ternary operator solution (see Zohar Peled's answer):

```
using System.Linq;

...

string original = "Some string here"; 
string result = "******" + string.Concat(original.Skip(6));
```

If you want to preserve the length of short (less than 6 character string):

```
// if original shorter than 6 symbols, e.g. "short" 
// we'll get "*****" (Length number of *, not 6)
// if original has six or more symbols, e.g. "QuiteLong" 
// we'll get "******ong" as usual 
string original = "short"; 
...
string result = new string('*', Math.Min(6, original.Length)) + 
                string.Concat(original.Skip(Math.Min(6, original.Length)));
```

You may want to have the routine as an *extension method*:

```
public static partial class StringExtensions {
  public static string MaskPrefix(this string value, int count = 6) {
    if (null == value)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("value"); // or return value
    else if (count < 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count"); // or return value

    int length = Math.Min(value.Length, count);

    return new string('*', length) + string.Concat(value.Skip(length));
  }
}
```

And so you can put as if `string` has `MaskPrefix` method:

```
string original = "Some string here";
string result = original.MaskPrefix(6);
```

Comment: I think you don't need Min in string.Concat(original.Skip(Math.Min(6, original.Length))) in second example, skip will return empty string in case its shorter then 6 characters.

Comment: @Alex Lyalka: Thank you! I see that the code is *unclear*, that's why I've added comment. I wanted to demostrate than `Skip` will do without ternary operator (it's quite legal to skip *more* than `Length` characters)

Answer (score 0):

You can substring and mask it. Make sure to check if the input string is lower than 6 as below sample

```
    string str = "123456789345798";
    var strResult = "******"+str.Substring(6, str.Length - 6);
    Console.WriteLine("strResult :" + strResult);
```

Comment: Why "str.Length - 6"?

Comment: to get the max length of `str` and minus 6 chars

Comment: No need - just use the overload of substring that accepts only the start index...